# Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2 +y^2$ and $x +z=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid bounded by $z=x^2 +y^2$ and $x +z=0$. Need feedback.

---

$z=r^2\Rightarrow z\in{[0,r^2}]$ so $r\cos\theta+z=0$. Thus, for $z=0$, we have $r\cos\theta=0\rightarrow ({r=0})\lor(\cos\theta=0,\theta=\frac\pi2)$ and for $z=r^2$ we have $r\cos\theta +r^2 = 0\Rightarrow (r=0)\lor(r=-\cos\theta,\theta=0)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Part of what you wrote looks useful. Shifting over to the polar coordinate equations $z=r^2$ and $r\cos\theta + z = 0$, and then eliminating the $z$-coordinate to get the equation $r=-\cos\theta$ looks useful. But where do you go from there?

Comment: I mean the only thing I need are intervals for $\theta$ and $r$. I believe interval for $r$ is from $0$ to $-cos\theta$

Comment: Do you know the interval for $\theta$?

Comment: Having r interval it’s not the problem. But is r interval correct?

Comment: I mean $\theta$

Comment: Let me suggest that you expand your question by explaining in more detail exactly how you intend to set up the volume integral. As it is written so far, it is difficult to respond because it is hard to tell exactly what you are claiming to already know, and what more you want to know.

Comment: Everything I know is in the original post.

Comment: I don’t know how to calculate rest intervals

Comment: Has it to be necessarily solved in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: No, but I found it the easiest way. It's only for me to understand so I do not mind doing it other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I can see that you have correctly isolated an important point, namely that in your cylindrical coordinate volume integral the quantity $r$ will vary from $0$ to $-\cos\theta$. But you must still determine the $\theta$-interval and the $z$-interval. Determining these will require some geometric visualization skills.

On the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ the inequality $z \ge 0$ holds. Therefore, on the curve where that paraboloid intersects the plane $x+z=0$, we have $x=-z$, and so the inequality $x \le 0$ holds. So, the region of integration in the $x,y$ plane should be in the left half-plane where $x \le 0$. Expressed in polar coordinates, that region is given by $\pi/2 \le \theta \le 3\pi/2$, and that should be your interval of $\theta$ integration.

Let's put together what we know so far about the volume integral:
$$V = \int_{z \, = \, ?}^{z \, = \,?} \int_{r\,=\, -\!\cos\theta}^{r \, = \, 0} \int_{\theta \, = \, \pi/2}^{\theta \, = \, 3\pi/2} dV
$$
Still to do: insert the cylindrical coordinate form of $dV$ which I suspect you know, namely $dV = r \, dr \, d\theta \, dz$.

But we must also determine the interval of $z$-integration. For this purpose, you again need to visualize the geometry of the situation. As $\theta$ varies between $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$, the equation $r=-\cos\theta$ traces out a circle in the left half plane, as you might know from your study of polar coordinates. The region inside that circle is the domain of the $r,\theta$ double integral. Extending your visualization in the vertical direction, you should be able to see that in the part of space that lies over the inside of that circle, the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ lies below the plane $x+z=0$ (outside of that circle the paraboloid lies above the plane). Therefore the lower limit of $z$-integration is $z=x^2+y^2=r^2$, and the upper limit is $z=-x=-r\cos\theta$. Therefore we get our final integral:
$$V = \int_{z \, = \,r^2}^{z \, = \, -r\cos\theta} \int_{r\,=\, -\!\cos\theta}^{r \, = \,0} \int_{\theta \, = \, \pi/2}^{\theta \, = \, 3\pi/2} r \, d\theta \, dr \, dz
$$